# How to convert LambdaExpression to Expression<Func<T,bool>> in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, expression-trees, iqueryable, predicatebuilder

I have the below code that generates `LambdaExpression` at run time based on my `SearchTerm` inputs. I'm trying to build a dynamic `where` clause. However I'm stuck at how to convert from `LambdaExpression` to `Expression<Func<T,bool>>`

```cs
private static Expression<Func<T,bool>> GetSearchAppliedQuery(IEnumerable<SearchTerm> terms)
{
    var parameterExpression = ExpressionHelper.Parameter<T>();
    Expression finalExpression = Expression.Constant(true);
    Expression subExpression = Expression.Constant(false);

    // Build up the LINQ Expression backwards:
    // query = query.Where(x => x.Property == "Value" && (x.AnotherProperty == "Value" || x.SomeAnotherProperty == "Value"));

    foreach (var term in terms)
    {
        var hasMultipleTerms = term.EntityName?.Contains(',') ?? false;

        if (hasMultipleTerms)
        {
            var entityTerms = term.EntityName.Split(',');

            foreach (var entityTerm in entityTerms)
            {
                term.EntityName = entityTerm;

                // x => x.Property == "Value" || x.AnotherProperty == "Value"
                subExpression = Expression.OrElse(subExpression, GetComparisonExpression(term, parameterExpression));
            }
        }

        // x => x.Property == "Value" && x.AnotherProperty == "Value"
        finalExpression = Expression.AndAlso(finalExpression, hasMultipleTerms ? subExpression : GetComparisonExpression(term, parameterExpression));
    }

    // x => x.Property == "Value" && (x.AnotherProperty == "Value" || x.SomeAnotherProperty == "Value")
    var lambdaExpression = ExpressionHelper.GetLambda<T, bool>(parameterExpression, finalExpression);

    // How to do this conversion??
    Expression<Func<T,bool>> returnValue = ..??;

    return returnValue;
}
```

I'm trying to apply the result of above method to get the query as shown below:

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> GetQuery(IQueryable<T> inputQuery, ISpecification<T> specification)
{
    var query = inputQuery;

    // modify the IQueryable using the specification's criteria expression
    if (specification.Criteria != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(specification.Criteria);
    }

    ...
    return query;
}
```

So that my final query will look like,

```cs
query = query.Where(x => x.Property == "Value" && (x.AnotherProperty == "Value" || x.SomeAnotherProperty == "Value"))
```

**Edit-1:**
Adding the `ExpressionHelper.GetLambda` method as requested by @Ivan Stoev

```cs
public static class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static LambdaExpression GetLambda<TSource, TDest>(ParameterExpression obj, Expression arg)
    {
        return GetLambda(typeof(TSource), typeof(TDest), obj, arg);
    }

    public static LambdaExpression GetLambda(Type source, Type dest, ParameterExpression obj, Expression arg)
    {
        var lambdaBuilder = GetLambdaFuncBuilder(source, dest);
        return (LambdaExpression)lambdaBuilder.Invoke(null, new object[] { arg, new[] { obj } });
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetLambdaFuncBuilder(Type source, Type dest)
    {
        var predicateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(source, dest);
        return LambdaMethod.MakeGenericMethod(predicateType);
    }
}
```

Am I missing something very basic or doing anything wrong? Please assist.

Comment: What is `ExpressionHelper.GetLambda` method? Can we see it?

Comment: added `ExpressionHelper.GetLambda` and other methods in Edit - 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExpressionHelper.GetLambda<T, bool>` method used to obtain the lambda expression hides its actual type, which is the desired `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`, so all you need is to use a cast operator:

```
return (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)lambdaExpression;
```

Or better, either change the result type of `ExpressionHelper.GetLambda<TSource, TDest>` to `Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>>`, or don't use that helper method - when you know the generic type arguments at compile time, simply use one if the generic [Expression.Lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.lambda?view=netframework-4.8) methods (`ExpressionHelper.GetLambda<TSource, TDest>` seems to be the equivalent of  `Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TDest>>`), e.g.

```
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(parameterExpression, finalExpression);
```